# Questions regarding JPA spec jar (javax.persistence.jar)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, websphere, eclipselink

I have some questions regarding the jar of the [official JPA 2.0 spec jar](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) (`javax.persistence.jar`)
(often also bundled with JPA implementations or application servers, sometimes named slightly differently):

**Questions:**

1. **Where** can I find the *official* **sources** of this jar?
2. It seems that there's a version 2.0 and 2.0.1 of this jar. Is there any **changelog**/release notes?
3. I realised that **IBM WebSphere** seems to use a **modified version** of this jar. Is this a regular approach for this jar/the JPA spec? What is different?

***UPDATE:***

Just for clarification: I'm **not asking** about **actual JPA implementations** but the official `javax.persistence` classes which are part of the JSR/JPA spec in a binary form.

Comment: 1) I doubt you'll get the official source from IBM. Is there a reason you need to see the source? 2) Its likely that the changes that would happen between 2.0 and 2.0.1 are just some bug fixes. I wouldn't worry about it unless there is a specific bug you're trying to deal with. 3) What do you mean by modified verion? The JPA implementation provided by IBM should be compliant with the JPA specification.

Comment: See this request for the jar to be put in Maven (requiring the source jars too) http://java.net/jira/browse/JPA_SPEC-19

Answer (score 1):

WebSphere is using a modified version of OpenJPA, it is basically the code of OpenJPA but with enhancement coded in IBM.

1. You can not get the sources, but they are mostly identical to OpenJPA so for most things you can check the OpenJPA sources
2. IBM does not provide a changelog for that, you can look at the changed in WebSphere fixpacks to try and understand what was change and combine it with the official changelog for OpenJPA
3. This is standard, IBM adds code to make OpenJPA works tightly with WebSphere so they add code, this still holds to the specification so there is no problem.

About the specification jar:

WebSphere does not use the specification Jar made by Oracle, they use the specification implementation made by Apache (Apache Geronimo JSR-317 JPA 2.0).
This is why the jar is different.
The specification does not requires you to use the jar implemented by Oracle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - but I just want to point out that I'm not talking about the actual JPA implementation but the javax.persistence jar which is something slightly different. I've edited the question.

Comment: The 2nd part of your answer contradicts to the answer of Eelke who  states that the JSR jar binaries originate from the eclipselink project - who's right? (he has a convincing point of the eclipselink references in the jar)

Comment: Extract the jar and you'll see some Geronimo packages inside (org.apache.geronimo...)

Comment: Eclipselink might be using the same jar but its getonimo spec jar

Answer (score 0):

EclipseLink is the reference implementation for JPA. When you look at the contents of the jar it is clearly coming from eclipselink.

You can download eclipselink [here](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/ri.php). The minimal bundle contains a jar providing the sources for javax.persistence (among other things).